# iterate through a dictionary with duplicate keys python

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
dictk={"hi":1, "hi":3, "o":7, "o":2, "p":1, "e":5}
```

```
for key, val in dictk.items():
    print(key, val)
```

output:

```
hi 3
o 2
p 1
e 5
```

These are not all the pairs in the dictionary, is there a way to get all of them,
such that the output will be something like this:

```
hi 1
hi 3
o 7
o 2
p 1
e 5
```

Thank you

Comment: Short answer: no! That dict of yours (as any other dict) does **not** have duplicate keys (just because there are duplicates in the dict literal that creates the dict does not alter that fact).

Comment: Well, a complex answer is for you to turn your dict into a string first, which *might* then be `json` and then get `json` to parse them with a custom hook to get at the duplicates. What you have currently is some python code which will necessarily discard duplicates whilst creating the `dict`.

Comment: If that's something you need, change it to list of tuples/lists.

Comment: Please review https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary can contain only one instance of a key.

If you print your dictionary object `dictk`, you will see it has all distinct keys.

```
dictk={"hi":1, "hi":3, "o":7, "o":2, "p":1, "e":5}
print(dictk)
```

Output:

```
{'hi': 3, 'o': 2, 'p': 1, 'e': 5}
```

You'll need a list of values to have multiple values for a key.

If you have repeated keys then the last value will overwrite other values written previously for that key.